# Is it possible to interactively visualize 10000 31x31 contour plots?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, contour

I have a question on feasibility of visualizing 10,000 31x31 contour plots, and if it is feasible, what technologies/solutions would be able to handle this.

Requirements:
1) I have a 31x31x86x127 Matrix. Each 31x31 slice contains Z-coordinates, and a contour can be generated for each slice (basically figuring out where this slice crosses Z=0).

2) I want to show one 31x31 slice at a time, with the option to loop through all 86x127 other slices. I want to do this through two slider bars, one controlling the (1:86) index and the other bar controlling the (1:127) index.

3) I want this to be able to be done in a browser with reasonable load time (15 seconds or so)

So far I've tried pure d3.js (issue is the data will be too much for JS to load into DOM) and plotly.js (was able to get 31x31x127 working, but adding in 86 of these would not be possible for the browser to handle).

Any suggestions?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Are you saying that you've tried to do this and the performance wasn't good enough or are you asking whether this can be done in principle?

Comment: The approaches I've tried don't work, so I'm wondering if this can be done in principle.

Comment: You could use canvas instead of SVG.

Comment: Would that be D3 with canvas instead of SVG? The issue is that any D3.js solution will involve loading all 10,000 slices into the DOM, which is impossible. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Canvas doesn't use a DOM.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. But there is still the issue of loading in the data; even if it isn't loaded into the DOM, the browser would still have to feed it into D3 for the data-binding onto Canvas. Would this be feasible?

Comment: There wouldn't be that much data binding either as there's no DOM. Loading the data itself would depend on the size and the speed of the connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90834/discussion-between-txizzle-and-lars-kotthoff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only looking to draw one 31x31 contour plot at a time, this shouldn't really be an issue.

1. Load the data in browser (e.g. using `d3.csv`).
2. Add on-change event handlers to your sliders that plots the corresponding 31x31 contour plot

Here's an example: http://etpinard.github.io/plotly-dashboards/contours-with-csv-data/ (using dropdown instead of sliders).

If step 1. is taking too long for your interest, you could split up the data file and have the on-change slider event handlers load (and cache) the data needed for one 31x31 contour plot.

Comment: I have tried this with pure D3 (not Plotly), and the issue I got is that it wouldn't scale to 10,000 separate CSV files

Comment: It actually did! 82 MB of 10,000 csv files lol. Somehow it's still super fast.